# Auto Update DataGrid after data insert/delete

Tags: wpf, datagrid, auto-update

I'm using LINQ to entities to insert and delete data from a DataGrid that is displayed on the homepage of my WPF application. I was wondering if there was a way or a DataGrid feature that would make my DataGrid auto-update and show changes upon insert/delete by itself rather than me having to re-execute the LINQ query that fills the datagrid (which is how i am achieving this now).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean when changes are made in the *database* (not just objects in code)?

Comment: when changes are made in the database, basically i have a feature where a user can enter his/her details in a form then submit it to the database, i have a linq query that collects and submits those changes to the database, i want it so that when context.SaveChanges() is called and the entry is successfully submitted to the DB then my homepage datagrid automatically updates and shows the new record. Trying the ObservableCollection<T> now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, bind your datagrid to an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx), or even better, to an [Asynchronous Multi-threaded ObservableCollection](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/collections/AsyncObservableCollection.aspx)...